# UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCell IndexPath error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I am new to `UICollectionView`s, and I keep running into a specific error when I try to add `UICollectionViewCell`s programmatically.

In my app, I have one `UIViewController` that holds a `UIView`. Within this `UIView`, there are a few objects on the top half, and the bottom half holds a `UIScrollView`. This `UIScrollView` holds a `UICollectionView`.

I am attempting to add custom `UICollectionViewCell`s to the `UICollectionView` programmatically, and I keep getting this error:

```
[myViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e01f5e0
2013-04-23 16:19:02.726 myAppName[28121:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[myViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e01f5e0'
```

I've tried almost every solution from somewhat similar threads, but nothing has worked.

Here's the code that I believe is producing the problem:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)myCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)myCollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
  NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [myCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  UILabel *myCellTextLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
  [myCellTextLabel setText:cellData];

  return cell;
}
```

I can post any more information that is requested!

Comment: UICollectionView inherits from UIScrollView, so you probably don't need to put it inside another scroll view.

Answer (score 2):

Read the error message; you're missing a method, because you've named your method incorrectly.

> `[myViewController collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance `0x1e01f5e0`

That means your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method is missing.  And if you look at the definition of your method, you'll see you actually called it `myCollectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: THIS FIXED MY PROBLEM! I was using the actual name of my collectionView instead of just "collectionView" in the method. This makes so much sense now. I see my rookie mistake.